# How display Yii2 pagination in GridView widget on and top and bottom part of table?

Tags: yii2

How display *Yii2 pagination* in GridView widget on and  top and bottom part of  table

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this in GridView widget configuration:

```
'layout' => "{summary}\n{pager}\n{items}\n{pager}",
```